# Allowing a user to select null from an html <select> drop down

Tags: null, html-select

I've got a dropdown select box on my site.  The field is not required.  If the user accidentally makes a selection, is there an easy way to allow the user to reset the field to null?

The only thing I can think is to have the first option be a "Please make a selection..." and then see if the user has selected that option, and set the corresponding value to null.  That just feels kinda hacky.

Comment: Incidentally, that's the way I've usually seen it done.

Comment: Hacky, sure, but quite typical.

Comment: I have the same gripe with radio buttons.  Once you select one, there's no way to revert back to the original state.  Ideally with a checkbox group, one should be selected by default.

Comment: yeah that's how everybody does it ! just set the value of "please .." to like "-1" or like you said "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example will make the user able to reset the select without seeing the "null" option.
http://jsbin.com/ojozar/2

```
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1" >option 1</option>
    <option value="2" >option 2</option>
    <option value="3" >option 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="reset" id="resetbtn" />
```

js :

```
  $('#resetbtn').click(function(){
    $('select#select').prepend('<option selected="selected" value="null" class="null"></option>');        
  });

  $('select#select').bind('focus click mouseup',function(){
    $(this).find('option.null').remove();
  });
```